# how to edit the header thickness in a scrbook package

Tags: scrbook

[image: the error message]
Hi! I am constantly getting this error while setting the header line thickness and I tried using what they are asking but its not working. With the current command, i am already getting the line but it is not approved and there are then compilation problems. Also the line is somehow gray. Can we change the color back to black? I would appreciate some help. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TME. Please edit your question, adding to it a minimal working example (MWE), so that others can compile it.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}` or `\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt}`. By default the line gets the same color as the text in the header. Please add an MWE showing your issue.